# How to modify this function that calculates angle between 2 points

Tags: angle, points

finally after a lot of searching i found the function that i've been looking :

```
public double getAngle(Point centerCircle)
{
    double angle1= Math.atan2(centerCircle.y-this.y,centerCircle.x-this.x);
double angle2= Math.atan2(0,centerCircle.x-(centerCircle.x*2));
return Math.toDegrees(angle2-angle1);
}
```

sorry but i am kind of retarded for math, so what do i need to change to this function so it follow :

where 3 O'Clock is **90** and 12 O'Clock is **180** degrees

instead of

where 3 O'Clock is **0** and 12 O'Clock is **90** degrees

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If *angle1* and *angle2* are in radians, just add PI/2, like this:

```
return Math.toDegrees(angle2-angle1+(Math.PI/2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for a few different things here, so I'll see if I can cover all the bases.

1) If you are looking for the angle between two points (with the same origin/center point), it doesn't matter which direction 0/90/180/270 point as long as they are consistent. The angle will be the same regardless of the orientation.

2) If you are looking for the angle of a point E at (ex, ey) with an origin at (cx,cy) and 0 degrees pointing down and increasing counterclockwise (as you asked), then you can use the formula in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9614122/650365) to get the angle based on 0 degrees = 3 o'clock. Then add 90 degrees to get the final result. (Subtract 360 if necessary.)

3) You can use the steps in #2 to calculate the angle for two different points, then subtract one from the other to get the angle between them.

```
getAngleBetweenAAndB(Point A, Point B){
  return abs(getAngle(A) - getAngle(B));
}
```