# Make an element spin around its own axis in both directions, with jQuery and CSS3

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation, touch

I've implemented a record player and I successfully got it spinning clockwise, however, I'd love to make it spin both ways. :-)

I have adapted a script I found, added some touch events, because I need it to work on iPad primarily.

Here's what it looks like:

```
function getDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    return Math.sqrt((x1-x2) * (x1-x2) + (y2-y1) * (y2-y1));
}
var div = $("#turntable");
var rotation = 0; 
var isDragging = false;

div.bind('touchstart mousedown', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    isDragging = true;
    lastX = position(event).x;
    lastY = position(event).y;
});
div.bind('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    isDragging = false;
});
div.bind('touchmove mousemove', function(event) {
    if (isDragging) {
        var curX = position(event).x;
        console.log(curX);
        var curY = position(event).y;
        console.log(curY);   
        rotation += getDistance(curX,curY,lastX,lastY); 
        var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)';
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
        });  
        lastX = curX;
        lastY = curY;
    }
})
```

I'll need to have an if inside my touchmove event that checks what direction you're spinning in, but I can't really figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Or if you have another approach, I'd be happy to hear it.

Here a link to the original jsfiddle where I took the script from:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AM5tU/16/)

Comment: and you expect someone at this site to rewrite this code to fit **your** specifications? ..but this is not a freelancing site :(

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your code is set up to add a certain number of degrees based on how far the mouse has moved while mousing over the `<div>` you have. This sadly won't make for accurate spinning - if you spin your mouse closer to the center of the circle, it will spin more slowly than the mouse, and if you spin it around the bounding box (in the border radius cutoff area), it will actually spin *faster* than the mouse. Additionally, since you only check for the distance covered when the mouse moves, it will always be positive, resulting in one-directional spinning.

What you need to do is formulate a different formula, [which calculates **the angle traveled by the mouse**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614109/how-to-calculate-an-angle-from-points) rather than the distance covered, and be sure to consider negative angles to allow for reverse rotation. After doing this, you can pass the resulting integer to the CSS assignment, and the spinning functionality should work properly.