# detecting collision angle between two circle

Tags: javascript, math, collision-detection

I'm detecting collision between two circles like this:

```
var circle1 = {radius: 20, x: 5, y: 5}; //moving
var circle2 = {radius: 12, x: 10, y: 5}; //not moving

var dx = circle1.x - circle2.x;
var dy = circle1.y - circle2.y;
var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);


if (distance < circle1.radius + circle2.radius) {
    // collision detected
}
```

My question is How can I detect the collision angle of `circle2`? (`circle2` is not moving). 
I would appreciate any explanation

Comment: Using the centre point of both circles you should be able to calculate the angle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614109/how-to-calculate-an-angle-from-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution :**

I think I got it :

`arccos((ra^2+rb^2-c^2)/(2*ra*rb))`

where :

- `c` is the distance between the centers of both circles (`distance` in your question)
- `ra` is the radius of the first circle
- `rb` is the radius of  the second circle

---

**Code :**
In JavaScript with your values, that should give :

```
const angleInRadians = Math.acos((circle1.radius*circle1.radius + circle2.radius*circle2.radius - distance*distance)/(2*circle1.radius*circle2.radius))
```

Note that the result is in *radians*, see [doc for `acos`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/acos)

If you want to have it in *degrees*, just use the conversion :

```
const angleInDegrees = angleInRadians / Math.PI * 180
```

---

**Explanation :**

The angle between the circles is defined as the angle between the *tangent lines* at any of the intersection points (if there are two points, both angles are the same).

The angle between tangents is the same as the angle between the corresponding radiuses (because radiuses are orthogonal to the tangent lines).

To get the angle between radiuses :

Draw a triangle between both centers and one of the intersection point. Use [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) based on the angle at the intersection point.

`c^2 = ra^2 + rb^2 - 2*ra*rb*cos(alpha)`

[image: sketch of 2 circles intersecting]

If you need more explanations, feel free to ask in comments .

Comment: (btw, anyone knows if we can use LaTeX on SO, like in [Math.SE] ?)

Comment: @adam west : it took me a bit of time, but I think I have the correct solution now. See my last version of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Comment: @adamwest : Also note that this may give you an *obtuse* angle instead of the *acute* one (like in my picture). To solve this, just take `Math.min(angleInDegrees, 180-angleInDegrees)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can detect the angle with some simple trigonometry.

tangent = Opposite/Adjecent

So `let angle = Math.atan(dy/dx)`